# SQL Server 2016 "FOR JSON" formatting nested JSON

Tags: sql-server, json

I'm trying to aggregate some nested JSON data using the `FOR JSON` clause supported by the latest version of SQL Server.

Let's say I write a function that uses the clause to export a piece of JSON data. Since no JSON type exists, this function returns an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` value.

Now suppose I wanted to use this piece of JSON as a value for a field in another function that returns JSON data through the `FOR JSON` clause.

Unfortunately I see no way to do this, other than storing it as a string. This effectively breaks nesting of JSON data.

For example, take this function that exports an array of JSON objects such as (directly from the Microsoft examples):

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetSalesOrderDetails(@salesOrderId int)  
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)  
AS  
BEGIN  
  RETURN (SELECT UnitPrice, OrderQty  
          FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail  
          WHERE SalesOrderID = @salesOrderId  
          FOR JSON AUTO)
END
```

Now if you tried to use this function inside another `FOR JSON` clause `SELECT`:

```
SELECT H.*, dbo.GetSalesOrderDetails(H.SalesOrderId) AS Details  
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader H
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Would produce something like:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 12,
    "Details": "[{\"UnitPrice\":12, \"OrderQty\":1}]"
  }
]
```

As you can see, the result of this query couldn't be parsed in one go, but would require a second parsing of the Details field.

Is there a way to tell the `FOR JSON` clause to interpret a field as a JSON array or a JSON object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built in function `JSON_QUERY` extracts an object or an array from a JSON string.

This query should work.

```
SELECT
    H.*, 
    JSON_QUERY( dbo.GetSalesOrderDetails(H.SalesOrderId) ) AS Details
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader H
FOR JSON AUTO
```

`

Comment: Unfortunately the return value of the `JSON_QUERY` function is still `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, so the outer `FOR JSON AUTO` clause still interprets it as a string

Comment: JSON functions in Sql server operate on and return strings( varchar or nvarchar), whether or not the string is a correctly formatted JSON string will determine how FOR JSON AUTO parses it. 
Look at the section *Prevent double-escaped JSON in FOR JSON output* on
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt631706.aspx

Comment: I'm so sorry, I rechecked the tests I made yesterday and, in fact, your solution works! I don't know how I missed that! By the way, is the engine parsing and stringifying JSON for every level where JSON_QUERY is present? That might be a pretty big hit on performance right?

Comment: yes calling the JSON_QUERY function will require it to parse anything passed to it. I wouldn't worry too much about performance though.